# AFNetworking: AFHTTPClient with subdomains

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I'm using `AFNetworking` and I want to create an instance of `AFHTTPClient`.
This class initializer requires a `baseUrl` parameter. If I pass `"www.mysite.com"`, how can I later use the same client with a subdomain? For example "`users.mysite.com`"

I don't want to create a different client for each subdomain I use. Also, I can't change the `baseUrl` as it is read only.
Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to specify a relative path - you can specify an absolute one.

From the docs:

> Both `-requestWithMethod:path:parameters:` and `-multipartFormRequestWithMethod:path:parameters:constructingBodyWithBlock:` construct URLs from the path relative to the `-baseURL`, using `NSURL +URLWithString:relativeToURL:`. Below are a few examples of how `baseURL` and relative paths interact:

```
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/v1/"];
[NSURL URLWithString:@"foo" relativeToURL:baseURL];                  // http://example.com/v1/foo
[NSURL URLWithString:@"foo?bar=baz" relativeToURL:baseURL];          // http://example.com/v1/foo?bar=baz
[NSURL URLWithString:@"/foo" relativeToURL:baseURL];                 // http://example.com/foo
[NSURL URLWithString:@"foo/" relativeToURL:baseURL];                 // http://example.com/v1/foo
[NSURL URLWithString:@"/foo/" relativeToURL:baseURL];                // http://example.com/foo/
[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example2.com/" relativeToURL:baseURL]; // http://example2.com/
```

> Also important to note is that a trailing slash will be added to any `baseURL` without one, which would otherwise cause unexpected behavior when constructing URLs using paths without a leading slash.

So you can do stuff like `[[MyClient sharedClient] getPath:@"http://users.mysite.com/etc" ...]` and it'll resolve to the full URL.  You can also write your own `getPath` methods like `getUserPath` - the implementation is simple.

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar issue by creating multiple singletons:

```
+ (id)sharedJSONClient
{
  static dispatch_once_t pred = 0;
  __strong static id __jsonClient = nil;
  dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
    __jsonClient = [[self alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[TSAPIURL stringByAppendingString:@"json/"]]];
    [__jsonClient setParameterEncoding:AFFormURLParameterEncoding];
    [__jsonClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
  });
  return __jsonClient;
}

+ (id)sharedXMLClient
{
  static dispatch_once_t pred = 0;
  __strong static id __xmlClient = nil;
  dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
    __xmlClient = [[self alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[TSAPIURL stringByAppendingString:@"xml/"]]];
    [__xmlClient setParameterEncoding:AFFormURLParameterEncoding];
    [__xmlClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]];
  });
  return __xmlClient;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I wrote in my question - I don't want to create a different client for each subdomain.